# Passing parameter from one mapping to another in spring

Tags: java, spring, controller, mapping

Hello I have a problem with passing parameters from one mapping to another in spring.

```
@GetMapping("/board")
    public String showBoard(@RequestParam("categoryId") int id, Model theModel) {

        ForumCategory forumCategory = forumService.getForumCategory(id);
        ForumPost forumPost = new ForumPost();
        List<ForumPost> forumPosts = forumCategory.getForumPosts();
        theModel.addAttribute("forumCategory", forumCategory);
        theModel.addAttribute("forumPosts", forumPosts);
        theModel.addAttribute(forumPost);

        return "board";
    }

@PostMapping("/saveForumPost")
    public String saveForumPost(@ModelAttribute("forumPost") ForumPost forumPost, @ModelAttribute("forumCategory") ForumCategory forumCategory) {

        forumService.saveForumPost(forumPost);
        forumService.saveForumCategory(forumCategory);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

So what I want to do is to save forumPost and add it to the forum category with id from /board mapping. Is there a way to pass parameter from /board mapping to /saveForumPost mapping?

Comment: are you doing a redirect from /board to /saveForumPost ?

Comment: Not enough information. Would need to see the flow. Can't you just get the ID from `forumCategory` in the `Post` method?

Also worth pointing out this can potentially be abused. There's nothing to stop the user from changing the `forumCategory` id.

Comment: You mean by adding "@RequestParam("categoryId")" in post mapping? If so it doesnt work. Also forumCategory id is just forum topic so changing it sends you to a different part of the forum.